# Bean casting error from nested injections

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am working with Spring Integration with my project right now, specifically with MessageChannel/PublishSubscribeChannel. What I am trying to achieve is to create a broker module, so that other part of the system can call this module to send message to a specific MessageChannel.

Here is what I am doing now in the broker module:

```
@Configuration
public class BrokerConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public MessageChannel brokerChannel1() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
  }
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class BrokerA {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("brokerChannel1")
  public MessageChannel messageChannel;

  public void sendAMessage() {
    messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("This is a message!").build());
  }
}
```

I have played around this setup by creating a SpringBootApplication within the broker module and it seems to work perfectly fine. However, when I try to use it in a different module of my system like this:

```
@Autowired
private BrokerA brokerA;

public void doSomethingHere() {
  brokerA.sendAMessage();
}
```

I get a ClassCastException like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel
```

And when I change messageChannel in BrokerA to the type of PublishSubscribeChannel, it will complain about PublishSubscribeChannel doesn't have a method called send().

This really baffles me. Any suggestions or comments? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an old version of Spring Integration on the classpath; `MessageChannel` etc was moved from `o.s.integration...` to `o.s.messaging` in Spring 4.0.

You need to use Spring Integration 4.x.

Comment: I have another maven dependency that depends on sprint-integration-core 3.x and there is no update for it. Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: You'd have to go back (override boot's dependencies) to Spring Integration 3.0.x for everything, but it's unlikely the boot starter/auto configuration stuff can be used for any SI components. Depending on what you're doing you might also have to drop back to Spring Framework 3.x which probably rules out boot altogether. You could look into loading that jar in a different class loader and provide a shim to convert the messages from one class to the other (and back again).

Answer (score 1):

Check your classpath, probably you have duplicated jars.

Comment: I scanned with Tattletale but there doesn't seem to be any duplicated jars. :/

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on my environment with last spring boot version without any version specification about spring and it's working just right, the only error is on

`MessageBuilder.withPayload("This is a message!")` it should be `MessageBuilder.withPayload("This is a message!").build()`

And I verified using `org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder`.

Comment: hi! Thanks for trying it out. I tried it within a dedicated server as well, and didn't run into any issues. I think the issue is somewhere among autowiring the broker class in a different module.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an explicit cast in the return statement of brokerChannel1() in BrokerConfiguration.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help.